# How should I request permissions when entering app from deep link?

Tags: android, android-permissions, deep-linking

I have two apps that both require a user to be logged in before creating the app databases.  One app is a launcher-type app that contains my AccountManager and links to my other apps.  All of my apps request storage permissions since they need local databases.

The problem I am currently having is when opening the second app for the first time through the launcher app.  If you open the app normally for the first time there is a splash screen that asks the user to select an account, and the storage permission dialog comes up here.  But if the user opens the app for the first time through a deep link, this splash page is skipped (since the deep link goes to a different activity).  So if the user opens the app for the first time from a deep link, I can make the permission dialog appear, but the app continues behind the popup and inevitably crashes because it cannot create its databases.  I can enable the permission, then try to launch the app again and everything works, but this is not nice.

What would be the best way to handle this scenario?  I was thinking about hacking together a way to freeze the app until the permission is accepted but I would prefer not to have to do that.